# Highcharts Stacked bar chart Tooltips

Tags: highcharts

In stacked bar chart,

```
{
                            name: 'Impressions',
                            type: 'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: x_axis,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' Imp'
                            }



                        },
                        {
                            name: 'On Target Impressions',
                            type: 'column',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data: on_axis,
                            tooltip: {
                                valueSuffix: ' OnTargetImp'
                            }

                            }
```

I want to add the point.y values of  on_axis  and x_axis data series and display them in a tool tip with ValueSuffix 'Imp'.Is it possible in highcharts?

Comment: Honestly it is unclear question, because in Data you have array of points (y values), so Im not sure why you would like to add point.y? Could you replicate your example as live demo and explain your case in more details?

Comment: On target impressions and Impressions are two series that form the stacked bar.I want to add  these two values and display in a single tool tip

Comment: You can use [shared](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.shared) parameter in tooltip.